# /etc/inputrc does not seem to be recognized as user on Ubuntu 8.04.2 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bashrc, inputrc

On a new installation of Ubuntu 8.04.2 LTS, logging in as a standard user does not maintain the keybindings (whether through sudo su -  or direct from ssh).  As the root user everything is fine and /root/.inputrc does not exist (only /etc/inputrc) which has its default settings.

In addition setting a ~/.bashrc and ~/.profile to the same as the root user (and chown'ing to user:user) has no effect.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: is /etc/inputrc the only place you're trying to change keybindings?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the terminal was set to /bin/sh instead of /bin/bash by default.  Switching to the correct terminal sorted things out!

FYI the installation is on a Rackspace Cloud Server, not sure if this applies to a default Ubuntu 8.04 installation.

This command is changing to bash as the default:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Comment: That's "shell" rather than "terminal".